# Bootstrap navigation elements getting pushed down when clicking toggler

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, navigation

Im using Bootstrap 4. My goal is to make navigation with toggler on left, text on center and text on right. The problem is that after I click toggler to reveal navigation, it's pushing down my navigation elements. What I noticed is that without changes in order property it's working good and not pushing down elements but Im trying to do this with order property as it looks simple and clean.

```css
body
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Navigation Start */
.navbar-bg-custom
{
  background-color: red;
}

.navbar
{
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar-brand
{
  order: 2;
}

.navbar-nav{

}

.icon
{
  order: 3;
}

.navbar-brand img
{
  height: 80px;
}
/* Navigation End */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
</head>
<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-bg-custom">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">This is getting pushed down on </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="icon">
    This too
  </div>
</nav>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code on my machine and got to know that when I remove the external style at least, the navabar brand is on it's position.

**I can assure you that if you avoid giving dimensional attributes like margin, padding or positional attributes to your html elements using your css code while using bootstrap, you won't face this issue.**

**I'll suggest you to use styles and dimensional attributes of bootstrap library in most of the cases.**

**The dimensions specified by you cause a deviation in the bootstrap's properties**

Just let me know if this answer was helpful.

Comment: Well brand is on it's original position but I don't want it here, I want brand to be in center, toggler on left and text on the right.

Comment: Hey... I got the solution for you... I'll be updating my existing answer